# What is "what we can or can't control" in stoicism?

Tags: stoicism, interpretation

Stoics, as a rule, shouldn't be psychologically affected by what they don't have any control over. But what kind of control are we talking about?
I do not have any control over the weather, therefore I shouldn't lose my patience when it starts raining.

However, one might say that I do not have any control over someone else's actions. On the other hand, we can still influence it by our reaction to it.
Is that under our control?

Another example could be, I don't like the place I live in.
Would stoicism advocate being patient and work on moving to a better place without complaining in the meantime?

Comment: You have to think at examples relevant to philosophy: [Passions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/#Pass).

Comment: See also [Epictetus](https://iep.utm.edu/stoicism/#H3) 'at the very beginning of the *Enchiridion*: “We are responsible for some things, while there are others for which we cannot be held responsible” (also translated as “Some things are up to us, other things are not up to us”).'

Comment: We have control over our influence on others, and not just by reacting to them, so that is what a stoic focuses on. Whether it results in changing their actions is out of stoic's hands, but it should not disturb them as long as they did their part in good faith. And the same with everything, do what you can and let the chips fall where they may. Control is precisely what is in one's power to do, and no further, it is not control "over" what may or may not get accomplished by it, even if that was the intent. Control for what is controlled, patience and composure for the rest.

Comment: "*Never complain, never explain.*"

Comment: @ScottRowe, *ati sundar*! As for the question, the interpretation of stoicism is *correct*, but we could *upgrade* it *or* we could *down grade* it. Up to you, mon ami, it's all up to you. Send me postcards. I'm off grid.